# Are there any HTML Editing Services?

Tags: html

I tried to Google this and didn't know where to start.

I have thousands of html templates that need to be hand edited because they are malformed so scripting my changes is darn near impossible or at least each file would need to be opened and reviewed by a human anyway.

**Are there any services or companies where you can pay for HTML editing on a per file basis?**

For some reason this sounds unscrupulous to me on the surface (like I picture sweatshop children clacking away at keyboards), but I would intend to pay a fair price.  This is simply a matter of having neither the time or manpower on staff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also consider [Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/) for this. It would be simple enough for you to establish a per file charge, it's generally quite cheap, and the workforce is very scalable.

Comment: +1 A good idea. Amazon Turk distributes the work to many individuals though, so if you are concerned about consistency, you might not get it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking around on freelance companies. They seem to charge insanely low prices and have massive power. These guys do things I thought would take weeks in like 2 days for $10. It's pretty crazy.

http://www.freelancer.com/

Also there are more than just individuals on these sites. I remember one guy who had a whole team (most likely from somewhere in india) that you could hire for projects.

Do note- With large projects quality may be a concern. If you use freelancers make sure you have STRICT (lawyer strict) guidelines on quality. On top of that make sure they understand them.

Answer (score 0):

odesk.com is another site that is kind of like freelancers.  i have used odesk a few times.  As a side note,  you can find local USA people to do this as well.  If you cant find someone let me know I would be happy to help you out.  Hope some of this helps.

Cheers